# What is the difference between simple service and daemon service ubuntu e,g smbd

Tags: ubuntu

I am totally confused , what is the difference between

ssh and sshd

samba or smb or smbd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SSH" is the protocol. `ssh` is the client. `sshd` is the server.

"Samba" is the software. "SMB" is the protocol. `smbd` is the file-sharing server (compare: `nmbd`, the name-sharing server).

Comment: basically if "d" is there then it is server and if not then it is client

Comment: For the most part. the "d" stands for "daemon": Disk and Execution Monitor. They watch for stuff happening, and make other stuff happen back.

Comment: Just a nitpick, Disk and Execution Monitor is a backronym, not the real meaning of the word "daemon"